# Extract raster data by feature attributes/elements

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, arc-hydro, extract-by-mask

I have a DEM raster, and a shapefile consisting of ~20 lines of steepest descent, created from the "flow Path Tracing" tool in Arc Hydro. Though the lines are all in the same shapefile, I wish to maintain their distinction (each has a separate ObjectID in the attribute table) in extracting DEM elevation values through a tool such as Extract by Mask. Using Extract by Mask with the line shapefile just produces one raster, with no separation between different lines.

Is there a way to extract DEM raster values corresponding to line location and maintain separate line IDs, so that I can later export them to Matlab for further analysis?

I'm currently using ArcMap 10.2

Comment: I don't think raster will work. Interpolate streams to 3d, extact vertices and add geometry attributes (z) to them. Another option is using second raster storing IDs, providing streams do not merge downstream

Comment: Have a look at the Add Surface Information  or the Interpolate Shape tools in the 3D Analyst Tools Toolbox.